# when Windows 7 tries to "check disk for consistency" on startup, can I make it wait more than 10 seconds?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, boot

like, how about making it count down 3600 seconds to make sure that I have time to tell it to take a hike? How does it know to wait for precisely 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191603)

Quote:

> 1. Start Registry Editor (Regedit32.exe) and locate the following subkey:
>      \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
> 2. Add the following information:
>      Value Name: AutoChkTimeOut Data Type: DWORD Value: The value in units of seconds (for example, a value of 60 equals 1 minut
>
> The autochk.exe count down time is controlled by the following
>   registry entry:
>   \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
>   \AutoChkTimeOut
>
> If the entry is not found, the default count down of 10 seconds will
>   be used. If it is set to 0 second, there will not be any count down.
>   If it is set to more than 3 days (259,200 seconds), the default value
>   will be used.

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like there is a registry entry](http://www.hiren.info/downloads/registry-tweaks/) that controls it.

> Modifying the Disk Check Autochk.exe Time-out (Scandisk Delay) Value from 10 seconds to 3 Seconds

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager]
"AutoChkTimeOut"=dword:00000003
```

That info is for XP, it might work on 7.  Have not tried it myself.